# Error creating MySQL Trigger for Delete

Tags: mysql

I am using this to prevent any delete from MySQL table `user`

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_no_del BEFORE DELETE on user
FOR EACH ROW SET
BEGIN
    UPDATE user SET a=0;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

But mysql is giving some syntax error, any ideas what i am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW SET` should be `FOR EACH ROW` instead, as mentioned by @catalinetu. But you should ever include the error message you get, so we know with what problem we're confronted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_no_del//

CREATE TRIGGER tr_no_del BEFORE DELETE ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE USER SET a=0;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: error: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table' `

Comment: @user2955412 Well then remove this existing trigger first.

Comment: mysql version: 5.1.73-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPLv2)

Comment: can you check if there are other triggers?

Comment: try with this to view the triggers on user table  SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE table = user; and with this to view the events from current database SHOW EVENTS FROM database;

Comment: ok, my bad, i was checking the Triggers on a different table than `user`, this is why it was showing blank. When i checked it from the Database level, it showed me that trigger. So, it was all good just my bad i was not checking triggers on the correct level. Sorry guys and thank you for your help!